# Windows machine to send email

Tags: windows, email, smtp

What software/package required on a new Windows machine (say Win10) to send email. My understanding is that it needs SMTP client kind of software installed to communicate with an SMTP server to able to send email. I know we can use telnet to an SMTP server on port 25 and send email. But what is not clear to me how an application will send email - does it need integration with SMTP client on that machine to communicate with SMTP server?

I think I have problem with basic concept here? Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

To just send an email message open a PowerShell session and type something like this:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "User01 <user01@example.com>" -To "User02 <user02@example.com>" -Subject "the subject" -Body "some body" -SmtpServer "smtp.fabrikam.coz"
```

PowerShell is included in all current Windows versions, more information on the  [Send-MailMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

Under the hood PowerShell is using classes in the .NET Framework. If your application is written in .NET itself, you can just use those same classes. Otherwise you could use a COM wrapper around .NET code and use the COM Object from your code. There are also third party components available which allow you to send email, but all of this is more a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

https://windowsreport.com/free-mail-server-windows-10/

The above link should give you some options. In a nutshell you need to install some time of mail server software on your windows instance.

If your just trying to setup an email client on your windows machine then you want to pick a client, install it, and then follow the instructions for that client on how to setup your email account. Usually this is going to be a POP3 or IMAP type of situation.